# Topological Sort giving incorrect result

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am newbie to Algorithms and was trying Topological sort (https://www.educative.io/collection/page/6151088528949248/4547996664463360/5657624383062016) and got stuck here. When I give numeric values it works fine , but when given string dependencies it is giving incorrect output

My Paths are as follows:

'sA'-->'sB' ,

'sA'--> 'sC' ,

'sB'--> 'sD'

So far Tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict
    class Graph:
        def __init__(self,vertices):
            self.graph = defaultdict(list) #dictionary containing adjacency List
            self.V = vertices #No. of vertices
        # function to add an edge to graph
        def addEdge(self,u,v):
            self.graph[u].append(v)
        # A recursive function used by topologicalSort
        def topologicalSortUtil(self,v,visited,stack):
            # Mark the current node as visited.
            visited[v] = True
            # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex    
            for i in self.graph[v]:
                if visited[i] == False:
                    self.topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stack)
            stack.insert(0,v)
        def topologicalSort(self):
            # Mark all the vertices as not visited
            visited = [False]*self.V
            stack =[]
            for i in range(self.V):
                if visited[i] == False:
                    self.topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stack)    
            # Print contents of stack
            print(stack)   
    g= Graph(4)
    g.addEdge('sA', 'sB')
    g.addEdge('sA', 'sC')
    g.addEdge('sB', 'sD')
    print(g.graph)    
    print("Following is a Topological Sort of the given graph")
    g.topologicalSort()
```

Expected output:

```
sA -> sB -> sD -> sC
```

Currently I am getting [3,2,1,0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the graph encoded in `self.graph` allows for graph vertices to be arbitrary objects (numbers, strings, etc.). However, while sorting the graph you are keeping track which vertices have been visited using integer indices and their corresponding values in the `visited` list. Since there is no mapping between the integers and vertex labels this gives wrong results. If `self.graph` were a regular dictionary this problem would be apparent, since the line

```
for i in self.graph[v]
```

would generate an error (you are passing as the key `v` an integer which is not a valid key in `self.graph`). However, since `self.graph` is a default dictionary, this produces the default value i.e. an empty list.

You can fix it e.g. as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) #dictionary containing adjacency List
    # function to add an edge to graph

    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)
    # A recursive function used by topologicalSort

    def topologicalSortUtil(self,v,non_visited,stack):        
        # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex    
        for i in self.graph[v]:
            if i in non_visited:
                non_visited.remove(i)
                self.topologicalSortUtil(i,non_visited,stack)
        stack.insert(0,v)

    def topologicalSort(self):
        # set of all vertices
        non_visited = set(self.graph.keys()).union(*list(self.graph.values()))
        stack =[]
        while non_visited:
            v = non_visited.pop()
            self.topologicalSortUtil(v,non_visited,stack)    
        # Print contents of stack
        print(stack)   

g= Graph()
g.addEdge('sA', 'sB')
g.addEdge('sA', 'sC')
g.addEdge('sB', 'sD')
print(g.graph)    
print("Following is a Topological Sort of the given graph")
g.topologicalSort()
```

This code replaces the `visited` list with a set `non_visited`, which at the beginning consists of all vertices. Then vertices are removed one by one as they are visited.

Comment: what should be corrected to acheive desired result?